# el notifyDataSetChanged no funciona con AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, recyclerview

Estoy intentado cargar un listado pero cada vez que intento actualizar la vista del recyclerview, no me carga los datos, sólo carga el primer registro, aquí os dejo el código:

```
public class LoadInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, People, Void> {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Context context;
    private PeopleAdapter peopleAdapter;

    public LoadInfo(RecyclerView recyclerView,ProgressBar progressBar, Context context){
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.context = context;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        peopleAdapter = new PeopleAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(peopleAdapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        InputStream flujo = null;

        try
        {
            flujo = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nombres);
            BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(flujo));

            String texto = lector.readLine();
            while(texto != null)
            {
                publishProgress(new People(texto));

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                texto = lector.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (flujo != null)
                {
                    flujo.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(People... values) {
        peopleAdapter.updateList(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

public class PeopleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PeopleViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<People> peopleList;

    public PeopleAdapter() {
        this.peopleList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public PeopleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_list, parent, false);
        return new PeopleViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PeopleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.getName().setText(peopleList.get(position).getName());
        holder.getCount().setText(String.valueOf(peopleList.get(position).getCount()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return peopleList.size();
    }

    public void updateList(People person){
        peopleList.add(person);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Te has asegurado de que tu while se ejecute mas de una vez?

Comment: Sí, lo he hecho.

Comment: Ya probaste el código de la respuesta?

Comment: Sí! lo acabo de probar y funciona muchas gracias.

Comment: Recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva, tal como marcar las respuestas como aceptadas y también puedes darle un voto a favor. Tal como se explica en el recorrido de [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente en tu metodo `updateList()`:

```
public void updateList(People person){
    peopleList.add(person);

    ArrayList<People> updatePeopleList = peopleList;
    peopleList.clear();
    peopleList.addAll(updatePeopleList)

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No es común actualizar los datos en el Adapter mediante `onProgressUpdate()`, pero puedes realizarlo de esta forma, después de actualizar los datos llamar `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(People... values) {
    peopleAdapter.updateList(values[0]);
    // Actualiza!
    peopleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

Otra opción es al terminar la ejecución de tu `AsyncTask` (`onPostExecute()`), puedes actualizar directamente los datos del Adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //Actualiza!  
     peopleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```